# Codeigniter global variables

Tags: codeigniter

I have an array of language names I use repeatedly throughout my application.  What's the best way to do that.  I tried this library, following an example on here.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Config extends CI_Controller
    {
        public $languages = '';
        public $languages_en = '';

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->languages = array('ar', 'cn', 'fr', 'de', 'it', 'jp', 'kr', 'pl', 'pt', 'ru', 'es', 'sk');

            $this->languages_en = array('ar', 'cn', 'fr', 'de', 'it', 'jp', 'kr', 'pl', 'pt', 'ru', 'es', 'sk', 'en');  
        }
    }
?>
```

And then I tried loading the library and calling the variable.  But I get an error that the action I requested is not allowed.

Is this the best way to do this?  Or is there a better way to create a global variable in CI? By the way, is the name of my class an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Config` would not be an allowed class name as CI already has a `Config` class.

However, I would create a config file to hold these arrays and just load that file when needed.

Docs: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/config.html

So in your config file `/application/config/languages.php`, you would put this:

```
$config['languages'] = array('ar', 'cn', 'fr', 'de', 'it', 'jp', 'kr', 'pl', 'pt', 'ru', 'es', 'sk');

$config['languages_en'] = array('ar', 'cn', 'fr', 'de', 'it', 'jp', 'kr', 'pl', 'pt', 'ru', 'es', 'sk', 'en');
```

Then, in your controllers, you can do this:

```
$this->config->load('languages');
$lang = $this->config->item('languages');
$lang_en = $this->config->item('languages_en');
```